# Can I still visit a "movie TV" establishment (MTV) in Taiwan?

Tags: taiwan, entertainment

I have read that before KTV was invented in Taiwan in the 1980s there were similar places for watching movies in private rooms called MTV but most closed around 1988 due to new intellectual property laws but that a small number survived by raising their prices.

Are there still any MTVs operating in Taiwan? Where can I visit one? I might be back there in a few months after I visit China and I've become fascinated with this topic.

This is hard to Google for since MTV is also a cable TV channel and since most of them closed before the Internet took off.

(I'm strictly looking for places using the term "MTV", "Movie TV", or "movie television". If it's something kinda the same but not using that term it's not an answer sorry.)

Comment: Similar establishments operated all over the CIS back in the 1990s, but all of them shut down when TVs and VHS/DVD players became cheap. I found a comment on a Russian forum stating that the last one in Moscow was closed around 2000.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can. There are still some in Taipei. [U2MTV](http://www.u2mtv.com/html/about/03.aspx) is one of the chains. You can pick the movie you want from the shelf (they're all legit copies, btw), then check out and pick a room. You can also order food from them for you to enjoy.

Just FYI, it's popular among teenagers because of the private suites... and you could guess what they might be doing in there... So, not the best place to enjoy the movie *alone*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there's still some operating. I visited my first one today in Kaohsiung, not to watch a movie, just to satisfy my curiosity.

Facade of [Open MTV in Kaohsiung](https://www.facebook.com/open.mtv/?fref=ts):
[image: Open MTV facade, Kaohsiung]

Apparently Open MTV only has older movies, from all eras, but not current releases. They also have TV shows.

Inside there were shelves and shelves of movies that looked a lot like a video rental place. There were "no photo" signs up so I didn't take any photos. The staff couldn't speak English so I couldn't ask them how it works. I'd say foreigners rarely visit.

Some of their information from a poster outside:
[image: Open MTV info, Kaohsiung]

(I would really appreciate it if somebody could translate the Chinese here. I have a hunch this could turn out to be a cheap alternative place to crash, a bit like manga cafes and internet cafes in Japan.)

---

In my other research, I have learned that there are two main MTV chains in Taiwan: [Kiss](http://www.kissmtv.com.tw/), and [U2](http://www.u2mtv.com/).

Comment: Seems it is open 24 hours but with the same rates. Interesting. I bet you anything the small print at the bottom is something like "cleaning charges 50"; the two 130 / 100 / 150 /130 are prices for food items (single / double); and the main chart is the price during week days and weekends. Based on my limited knowledge of how these places work, and my 0 knowledge of Chinese :-D

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to visit these make shift not so legal mini theaters.

The last time I saw such a thing was in a small town in India, and that too at least a decade back.

Basically, it was a shack/ tent where VHS/ or older prints were shown as small towns/ villages did not have/ could afford big movie theaters and people had no way of seeing movies besides these 'mini' theaters.

Given the satellite tv, cheap vcd/ dvd player, pirated media, downloaded media these days, you would be hard pressed to find such a place.

But, who knows there might be some remote corner where such a place is still operational and the operator peddles all of the above to a remote tribe for a small price.

Comment: I'm only interested in a place of this kind in Taiwan and only if it's called an "MTV" because I'm interested in the history of Chinese KTV. In Cambodia there were cafes in every village where all the chairs face a TV showing old movies but they're not what I'm looking for for this question. I've read that there are still some in Taiwan but that info might now be out of date.

Comment: In your original question you did not mention that you were specifically interested in the HISTORY of Chinese KTV as you just did in this comment. What seemed imperative was such places were of interest to you. Sorry, I was unable to help more.

Comment: Yes it's too easy to turn a question into a wall of text so I tried not to bloat it too much but left in important bits like "MTV" and Taiwan. Thanks though.